# Cannot embed Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-plus

As of...today, it seems, Google Maps no longer has embed code!

Can someone point me in the right direction, or maybe offer up some old embed code I could try to embed into something useful?

Here is the article explaining how to embed a Google Map:
http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/quick.html

I think this has to do with the Google+ Social Network "thing" that appeared in the last few days.

Also, I have tried the instructions in the link above both logged into a Google Apps account and not logged in to any Google account.

Comment: Our JavaScript-version implementation is working just fine: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html - don't have any implementations with their embed code. You may also want to edit your question to include the code you've tried.

Comment: I am using the Google Maps API V3 on a few other projects, and that works fine.  I just wanted to do a "simple" embed of a map into a static html page.  In the past, I could just lookup the location at maps.google.com and click the embed button.  Not, the embed button is not there.  So, I would like to find it, or, take someone elses embed code and try to modify it.  I don't seem to have any anywhere. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://maps.google.com - the embed box is now back.

I guess it was a temporary glitch.  I am pretty sure it was not on my side, I tried a few different machines and browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the embed code and it seems to be working correctly for me. Did you change anything on your page recently? Here is what I tried.

```
 <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&
amp;q=Birmingham,+MI&amp;aq=1&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=64.880423,107.138672&
amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Birmingham,+Oakland,+Michigan&amp;t=h&amp;z=12&
amp;ll=42.546701,-83.211319&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a 
href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&
amp;q=Birmingham,+MI&amp;aq=1&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=64.880423,107.138672&
amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Birmingham,+Oakland,+Michigan&amp;t=h&amp;z=12&
amp;ll=42.546701,-83.211319" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Comment: Thanks, that might get me somewhere!  Will see if I can hack it into what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your Maps Labs in order to use map embedding.  - [reference](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72644)

Answer (score 1):

Google maps has shifted settings link from bottom right to top left, left side of search bar

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to add Google Maps to your webpage. No API key needed.

```
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.584063, -5.928343),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>BLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
    <div id = "map-canvas"/>
</body>
```